# Youtube video to videoview android error

Tags: android, android-layout

I try this  code but video not appear.what is the issue? How can i solve it?

```
   VideoView vid1=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
  String video="http://www.youtube.com/embed/76JpysFZ2VM";
        Uri uri= Uri.parse(video);
        vid1.setVideoURI(uri);
        vid1.start();
```

Comment: I don't tested this but try this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView) from the [Youtube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/).

Demos:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications
- https://github.com/TheFinestArtist/YouTubePlayerActivity
- https://github.com/Glurt/EdenYouTube